# Criar variável data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Estou iniciando com Python, trabalho a muito anos com QlikView e estou fazendo a migração de algumas atividades de tratamento de dados para o Python.

Gostaria de criar um set com uma variável de dias e meses. A partir da data atual seguindo um padrão d-1 da seguinte forma:

```
29/11/2020 
28/11/2020
27/11/2020
26/11/2020
25/11/2020
...
```

Estava pesando em fazer um for, algo assim dentro de um loop.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar uma lista de datas e depois criar seu dataframe

### Criar lista de datas

```
>>> import datetime

>>> initial_date = datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1)

>>> initial_date
datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 0, 0)

>>> time_delta = datetime.timedelta(1)

>>> lista = []
>>>
>>> for i in range(10):
...     lista.append(initial_date + (time_delta * i))
...
>>> lista
[datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 2, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 3, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 4, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 5, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 6, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 7, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 8, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 9, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 10, 0, 0)]
```

### Criar dataframe

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"datas": lista})

>>> df
       datas
0 2020-01-01
1 2020-01-02
2 2020-01-03
3 2020-01-04
4 2020-01-05
5 2020-01-06
6 2020-01-07
7 2020-01-08
8 2020-01-09
9 2020-01-10
>>>
```

### Colocando cada data em uma coluna

```
>>> lista_vars = [f"vData{i}" for i in range(10)]

>>> to_df = dict(zip(lista_vars, lista_datas))

>>> df = pd.DataFrame(to_df, index=[1])

>>> df

      vData0     vData1     vData2     vData3     vData4     vData5     vData6     vData7     vData8     vData9
1 2020-01-01 2020-01-02 2020-01-03 2020-01-04 2020-01-05 2020-01-06 2020-01-07 2020-01-08 2020-01-09 2020-01-10
```

Para o output no formato que você quer, use o `strftime`

```
>>> df['vData0'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

1    01/01/2020
Name: vData0, dtype: object
```

Espero que ajude

Comment: Valeu, ajudou sim, porem preciso que cada data esteja em uma variável;
vData1 = 01/12/2020....vData90 = 03/09/2020, preciso que seja neste formato.

Comment: @Insert, atualizei o post em resposta ao seu comentário

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o **data_range** do **pandas**:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date
data_atual = date.today()

datas = pd.date_range(start = '11/05/2020' , end = data_atual, freq='D')[::-1]
```

Os parâmetros neste caso são o inicio e o fim do range de datas, note que ao final eu inverto a ordem utilizando das datas com `[::-1]`.

Saída:

```
pd.DataFrame({'Datas': datas})

         Datas
0   2020-12-01
1   2020-11-30
2   2020-11-29
3   2020-11-28
4   2020-11-27
5   2020-11-26
6   2020-11-25
7   2020-11-24
8   2020-11-23
           ...
22  2020-11-09
23  2020-11-08
24  2020-11-07
25  2020-11-06
26  2020-11-05
```

---

**Update**

Para criar várias colunas

Carregando os pacotes

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date
data_atual = date.today()
```

Criando o range de datas

```
datas = pd.date_range(start = '11/05/2020' , end = data_atual, freq='D')[::-1]
datas = datas.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

Criando as colunas

```
colunas = [f'vData{i}' for i in range(len(datas))]
```

Criando o Data frame de forma transposta

```
pd.DataFrame(datas, index = colunas).T
```

Saída:

```
      vData0       vData1     vData2      vData3      vData4      vData5    vData6      vData7       vData8     vData9      ...             
0   01/12/2020  30/11/2020  29/11/2020  28/11/2020  27/11/2020  26/11/2020  25/11/2020  24/11/2020  23/11/2020  22/11/2020  ...
```

Código:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date
data_atual = date.today()

datas = pd.date_range(start = '11/05/2020' , end = data_atual, freq='D')[::-1]
datas = datas.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
colunas = [f'vData{i}' for i in range(len(datas))]
pd.DataFrame(datas, index = colunas).T
```